# I get Unexpected End of File when i try and Run this Script

Tags: linux, bash

```
echo "Gateway: 192.168.0.1 | Interface: Wlan0" 
echo "###########################"
echo "1) Update Kali                    4) Thanks too.."
echo "2) Software and System Tools      5) Must View"
echo "3) Install Hacking Tools  6) Terminate Program"
echo ""
read Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4 Option4 Option5 Option6

if [ "$Option1" = "1" ]; then
echo "Test"
clear
if [ "$Option2" = "2" ]; then
echo "test"
clear
if [ "$Option3" = "3" ]; then
echo "Test"
clear
if [ "$Option4" = "4" ]; then
echo "chicken"
clear
if [ "$Option5" = "5" ]; then
echo "Test"
clear
if [ "$Option6" = "6" ]; then
echo "The End"
clear
```

Comment: you need to use the `fi` keyword (and depending on what you are trying to achieve `elif` might be needed too.

Answer (score 2):

The more robust way to present a menu is the `select` command

```
choices=(
  "Update Kali"
  "Software and System Tools"
  "Install Hacking Tools"
  "Thanks too.."
  "Must View"
  "Terminate Program"
)
PS3="Your choice: "
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $choice in
        "${choices[0]}")
            echo "Test"
            ;;
        "${choices[1]}")
            echo "test"
            ;;
        "${choices[2]}")
            echo "Test"
            ;;
        "${choices[3]}")
            echo "chicken"
            ;;
        "${choices[4]}")
            echo "Test"
            ;;
        "${choices[5]}")
            echo "The End"
            ;;
    esac
    break
done
clear
```